# MySQL Filter and Multiply the values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table. One field is "code", and this field has the code numbers starting from OYZ20001 to OYZ65000. Other field is "price", and it has the price of this items, e.g 84.40, 1214,20, so.
Now I need the increase the price of some items 20% percent (multiply by 1.2), I just have to increase the ones which code is starting as OYZ2 (OYZ2*), the other ones shouldn't be changed.
How can I make this filtered multiple calculation?
I have a very basic MySQL knowledge, but I made a backup of database :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what did you tried? did you read about the LIKE in sql?

Comment: Actually I couldn't combine both filtering and multiplying processes. As I said, I have a very basic knowledge in MySQL. I could filter the code's I want;

Comment: SELECT `code` FROM product WHERE code LIKE 'OYZ2%';

With this code, I can see the codes starting with OYZ2. But then, how can I multiply the "price" field by 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found the solution;

```
update product set price = price * 1.2 WHERE code LIKE 'OYZ2%';
```

seemed to work.